# What does it mean 'List(1, 2, 3)' in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala and I have one question - I read a lot of articles and some part of book, but I don't understand why I could create a list with

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
```

When I try to create a new List

```
val list = new List(1, 2, 3)
```

I get the following error

```
class List is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

i.e. List is abstract class, but why I could create it with just params?

I understand the following code:

```
class SomeClass

object SomeClass {
  def factory() = new SomeClass()
}

object Main extends App {
  val first = new SomeClass()
  val second = SomeClass.factory()
}
```

i.e. I could create a new SomeClass object with 'new' keyword or a factory method, but how can I create a new SomeClass neither 'new' keyword or factory method?

Answer (score 3):

List has a companion object which contains an apply method. When you are doing List(1,2,3) you are actually calling the apply method in the List object. The apply method creates a new instance of a default list implementation

Answer (score 0):

This might help illustrate @AssafMendelson's answer:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class AFoo(id: Int) {}

class Foo(id: Int) extends AFoo(id) {}

object AFoo {
  def apply(id: Int): AFoo = new Foo(id)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class AFoo
defined class Foo
defined object AFoo

scala> val foo = new AFoo(3)
<console>:13: error: class AFoo is abstract; cannot be instantiated
       val foo = new AFoo(3)
             ^

scala> val foo = AFoo(3)
foo: Foo = Foo@2e349cf2
```

In the above example, `AFoo` is an abstract class with a companion object (also named `AFoo`). The companion object has an `apply` method that creates a `Foo`, which is an implementation of `AFoo`. So while you can't directly instantiate `AFoo` with `new AFoo(3)` because it's abstract, you can call `AFoo(3)` to invoke the companion object's `apply` method and create a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 0):

`List[T]` is an abstract class in Scala.

When you call the `List()`, you are not calling the constructor method of the class `List`. Instead, you are calling the `apply()` method of the `List` object (lookup [singleton objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html) in Scala, more specifically, companion objects).

So `List()` is not the same as `new List()` with `List` being the class, instead, it is syntactic sugar for `List.apply(seq: T*)` with `List` being the companion object, and `seq` being a sequence of objects of type `T`. The `apply` method in this case simply calls `seq.toList()`.

The `List` class is abstract and has two subclasses - [`::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html) (also called cons) and `Nil` (actually, an object). `Nil` is an empty list and `::` is an object with two values - the head, or the first element, and the tail, or the list of the rest of the elements. You can call the `::` constructor, if you want, for example `new ::(1, new ::(2, new ::(3, Nil)))`. This has, by the way, the same result as writing `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil`, which is, in turn, syntactic sugar for `::(1, ::(2, ::(3, Nil)))`, where, again, you are calling the `apply` method of `::`.

There are several design reasons behind the `List` class being abstract. Knowing how it really works (the cons and `Nil`) is, for example, useful for pattern matching lists.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil` is `Nil.::(3).::(2).::(1)` and not `::(1, ::(2, ::(3, Nil)))`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no method named `foo` with the correct types in scope, and there is a method named `apply` with the correct types defined on `foo`, then

```
foo(bar, baz)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo.apply(bar, baz)
```

(This allows you to write your own "function-like" objects.)

So,

```
List(1, 2, 3)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
List.apply(1, 2, 3)
```

and [there is an `apply` method defined on the `scala.collection.immutable.List` object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#apply[A](xs:A*):List[A]).

> I could create a new SomeClass object with 'new' keyword or a factory method, but how can I create a new SomeClass neither 'new' keyword or factory method?

`List.apply` *is* the factory method.